# Printing custom data from database in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to write a web application where a user can sign in and see his prenotations. I already have done login and registration, and the user when sign in can see all the prenotations, including those from the other users. How can I obtain a custom table with only his prenotations?
I also tried a query in the StudRepository but it doesn't work.
I'm using Spring Boot with MySQL database. The db is made from three tables, one for student, named "studenti", one for reservations named "prenotazioni" and one for exam sessions named "appelli".

Thanks in advance.

Here is the Repository

```
package springuniversita;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface StudRepository extends JpaRepository<Studente, Integer> {

    Studente findByCodfiscAndPassword(String codfisc, String password/);
//Query tried below:

//  @Query("SELECT data, materia FROM prenotazioni JOIN studenti WHERE idstudente=studenti_idstudente AND codfisc=:codfisc") 
//  List<Studente> findByName(@Param("codfisc") String codfisc);
    
}
```

Controller

```
package springuniversita;

import java.util.Objects;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;



@Controller
public class LoginController {
    
    @Autowired
    private DBService studservice;
    
    
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "homepage";
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/login")

    public ModelAndView login() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("login");
        mav.addObject("studenti", new Studente());
        return mav;
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("studenti") Studente studenti) {

        Studente oauthUser = studservice.loginform(studenti.getCodfisc(), studenti.getPassword());

        System.out.print(oauthUser);
        if (Objects.nonNull(oauthUser)) {

            return "redirect:/profilo";

        } else {
            return "redirect:/login";

        }
}
}
```

Entity Studenti

```
package springuniversita;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="studenti")
public class Studente {

    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int idstudente;

    private @Column(name="nome") String nome;
    private @Column(name="cognome") String cognome;
    private @Column(name="telefono") String telefono;
    private @Column(name="email") String email;
    private @Column(name="password") String password;
    private @Column(name="codfisc") String codfisc;
    
    public Studente(Integer idstudente, String nome, String cognome, String telefono, String email, String password, String codfisc) {
        this.idstudente=idstudente;
        this.nome=nome;
        this.cognome=cognome;
        this.telefono=telefono;
        this.email=email;
        this.password=password;
        this.codfisc=codfisc;
                
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Studente [idstudente=" + idstudente + ", nome=" + nome + ", cognome=" + cognome + ", telefono="
                + telefono + ", email=" + email + ", password=" + password + ", codfisc=" + codfisc + "]";
    }

    public Studente() {
        
    }
//... getters and setters
```

Entity Prenotazioni

```
package springuniversita;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

    @Entity
    @Data
    @Table(name="prenotazioni")
    public class Prenotazioni {
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idprenotazione;
    private String data;
    private String materia;
    private int studenti_idstudente;
    private int appelli_idappello;
    
    public Prenotazioni() {
        
    }

    public Prenotazioni(int idprenotazione, String data, String materia, int studenti_idstudente,
            int appelli_idappello) {
        
        this.idprenotazione = idprenotazione;
        this.data = data;
        this.materia = materia;
        this.studenti_idstudente = studenti_idstudente;
        this.appelli_idappello = appelli_idappello;
    }
//... getters and setters
```

Comment: With Spring Data JPA, you should have a link between the different entities (Using `@OneToOne`, `@OneToMany`, etc.). I suggest to read the documentation on that.

Comment: you can create custom join query for that, check here please.https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-types